# Encapsulate TextView Hide/Show Method

Tags: java, android

Here is a snippet of Android `onCreate()` code.

```
View view1;
View view2;
boolean hidden = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.volunteer_screen);

    view1 = findViewById(R.id.sub1);
    view2 = findViewById(R.id.answer1);

    view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (hidden)
            {
                view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hidden = false;
            } else
            {
                view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                hidden = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I encapsulate this in some class, maybe with a constructor like:

```
Class(View view1, View view2, boolean state)
```

Not to call `setOnClickListener()` method to every new pair of `TextViews`?

Very big thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have this `android:onClick="myMethod"` in your xml of every text view, does that help you in any way? I mean you can set that once for every pair and have it call a method with parameters like the constructor you've given. Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a View (like a button) to hide or show another view right ?

if it's the case, on layout add the `android:onclick="myFunction"` and on your class create a method

```
public void myFunction(View v){
// do your logic
}
```

You can check what view call the function using `v.getId() == R.id.youViewId`, that way, you can build a switch or if logic and change the correct view.

Comment: Yep, this exactly implements the logic I wanted! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method like this in the same class:

```
private void setClickListener(final EditText sub, final EditText answer) {
    sub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            answer.setVisibility(hidden ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            hidden = !hidden;
        }
    });
}
```

And then you can call

```
setClickListener(view1, view2);
setClickListener(view3, view4);
...
```

I don't see useful to create a class just for that method, but obviously you can.

Comment: Big thanks for help! It works pretty good, but the poin was about the flags. Like every view has its own flag, that changes calling setClickListener. So I mixed ur advice with advice about switch statemnt and everything worked.
Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Include this view in your activity's XML file like this:

```
<your.package.CustomLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

---

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Created by ozgur on 09.06.2016.
 */
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private View view1;
    private View view2;
    private boolean hidden;

    public CustomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        //inflate the view that contains your view1, view2
        View wrapper = inflate(context, R.layout.view_custom_layout, this);
        view1 = wrapper.findViewById(R.id.view1);
        view2 = wrapper.findViewById(R.id.view2);

        view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (hidden) {
                    view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    hidden = false;
                } else {
                    view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hidden = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```